# Categorical Variables in Apache Spark using MLib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am relatively new to the world of Apache Spark. I am trying to estimate a large scale model using LinearRegressionWithSGD() where I would like to estimate fixed effects and interaction terms without having to create a huge design matrix.

I noticed that there is an implementation supporting categorical variables in DecisionTree

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/DecisionTree.scala#L293

that creates a Hash map from strings to integers and feeds it to the model. Has anybody attempted a similar exercise for linear models in Spark?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? I have a document of categorical variables which I want to convert to vectors. I tried solving it using HashingTF. I passed the row as Iterable[String] to hashingTf, which gave me a vector, which I used to create a Labeled Point. It works, but not sure if this is a correct approach. The correct solution in my opinion will be something which assigns a number to each word and we use that number to create a vector. I guess IDF does this, but I don't have the full vocabulary during training time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [One-Hot encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) to convert your categorical variable into the feature space where you can feed into the Linear Regression model.

For instance, if you have a categorical variable with the values: Low, Medium, High, you can encode it in three different integer features like below:

```
Category    Low Medium High
Low         1   0      0
Medium      0   1      0
High        0   0      1
```

This is just a method to do that, there are other approaches but if your categorical values aren't too large, One-Hot encoding the a good fit.

Comment: What if the categorial variables are large?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this problem for a while now. My estimation has a lot of categories so it is very inefficient to create the entire design matrix before feeding into MLlib. I am trying to modify the Spark source code to expand the rows when it runs the SGD inside the gradient descent. I will post the solution once I complete it.